# Abandon gerit review but save comments

Tags: git, gerrit

Somehow the links between my git commits and my gerrit review got all messed up, and it created another review.  I want to keep the new one, but abandon the old one.  However, if I abandon the old one, I assume I will lose all of the reviewer comments on the old one.  Is there anyway I can abandon a review, but save the comments?  I suppose I could just go through the old review and copy and paste all of the comments to a file, but I would prefer not to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you abandon the old change you won't lose the comments, they'll stay forever in the abandoned change (which won't be deleted).

Anyway... maybe it's better to abandon the new change (not the old one) where, I suppose, there aren't comments yet and push the commit again but to the right place (the old change).

Comment: Thanks.  There are reasons why I want to abandon the old one, however.  (E.g. somehow the owner got changed to someone who is not involved.)